# Proper way of doing asyncio.to_thread for selenium.webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

get almost zero performance gain

i think i missing something here..

```py
def take_page_scr(dict_item, driver) -> None:
    print(dict_item['id'])
    driver.get(dict_item['url'])
    driver.set_window_size(500, 900)
    (
        Image.open(
            io.BytesIO(
                driver.get_screenshot_as_png()
            )
        )
        .convert("RGB")
        .save(f"./dst/{dict_item['id']}.jpg", quality=85)
    )
    driver.quit()


def main_async(data):
    async def main(data):
        options = get_options()
        await asyncio.gather(
            *(
                asyncio.to_thread(
                    take_page_scr,
                    i, webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
                )
                for i in data
            )
        )
        print()
        print('#DONE')
    asyncio.run(
        main(
            data
        )
    )
    # 13.397236824035645
    # 13.26906943321228
```

here is basic setup

```py
def main_sync(data):
    options = get_options()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    for i in data:
        print(i['id'])
        try:
            driver.get(i['url'])
            driver.set_window_size(500, 900)
            image_bytes = io.BytesIO(driver.get_screenshot_as_png())
            img = Image.open(image_bytes).convert("RGB")
            img.save(f"./dst/{i['id']}.jpg", quality=85)
        except Exception:
            pass
    driver.quit()
    print()
    print('#DONE')
    # 16.04508686065674
    # 16.138192653656006
```

i guess problem in `webdriver.Chrome(options=options)`

```py
def main_sync_bad():
    options = get_options()
    [
        take_page_scr(
            i, webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        ) for i in data
    ]
    print()
    print('#DONE')
    # 76.43093585968018
    # 78.09915900230408
```

but i do not know how to propagate it to many threads

Comment: if you want to send one driver to many theads then you should create it before you create thread, `driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)` and later `for i in data: take_page_scr(i, driver)`. But I don't know if driver can run in threads - maybe every thread needs separated driver (and this means separated browser)

Comment: your function `take_page_scr` doesn't use any `async` function so it can't run faster then normal function. It may need rather `threading` or maybe `multiprocessing` to work at the same time. maybe you should create `Pool` with few processes. OR you should create few processes which run loop which get information from queue and main process should only send all data to queue.

Comment: @furas i have tried already `for i in data: take_page_scr(i, driver)` - in this case every screenshot are the same

Comment: @furas because there no async functions inside, IO is blocking, that's why i'm using threads (which are asyncio.to_thread under the hood). multiprocessing more suited for CPU bound jobs. problem in starting many browser instance, instead reuse it

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do won't work because webdriver isn't async. Consider pyppeteer instead.

Comment: @pguardiario that sad, but i guess you are right =( i chose the most popular lib, but it's bad, meh...  pyppeteer is also deprecated (yeah i know about new one, but author continue development under js..) and i found another alternative, called arsenic, and here is what they sad:  *While this library is asynchronous, web drivers are not. You must call the APIs in sequence. The purpose of this library is to allow you to control multiple web drivers asynchronously or to use a web driver in the same thread as an asynchronous web server.* maybe pyppeteer is the same, hm....

Comment: @Oleg pyppeteer is a wrapper for puppeteer, which is what you really want, but I'm assuming you don't know javascript.

Comment: @pguardiario yeah i know and so what? i also found playwritght, which is already looks awesome for me with that doc and dark mode, everything is nice and dandy mmm..

Comment: Hmm, You're welcome I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and the answer is - just don't use poor designed crappy things like lxml or selenium, use well documented, nice designed and supported libraries, even if they from micro$oft ...

```py
async def coro(dict_item: TestData, browser: BrowserContext) -> None:
    print(dict_item["hash"])
    page = await browser.new_page()
    await page.goto(dict_item["url"])
    await page.screenshot(path=f'./res/{dict_item["hash"]}.jpg', type="jpeg")


async def main() -> None:
    async with async_playwright() as p:
        browser: BrowserContext = await p.chromium.launch_persistent_context(
            user_data_dir=f"{Path.home()}/.config/chromium",
            executable_path="/usr/bin/chromium",
            viewport={
                "width": 500,
                "height": 900
            },
        )
        await asyncio.gather(*(coro(i, browser) for i in data()))
        await browser.close()
    # 7.495748519897461
    # 2.4119105339050293
    # 2.3972327709198
```

do it more than 2-3 times faster! and working with it just pure pleasure..!